# How to terminate a background process?

Tags: command-line, process, kill, background-process, job-control

I have started a wget on remote machine in background using `&`. Suddenly it stops downloading. I want to terminate its process, then re-run the command. How can I terminate it?

I haven't closed its shell window. But as you know it doesn't stop using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Answer (score 427, accepted):

There are many ways to go about this.

#### Method #1 - ps

You can use the `ps` command to find the process ID for this process and then use the PID to kill the process.

#### Example

```
$ ps -eaf | grep [w]get 
saml      1713  1709  0 Dec10 pts/0    00:00:00 wget ...

$ kill 1713
```

#### Method #2 - pgrep

You can also find the process ID using `pgrep`.

#### Example

```
$ pgrep wget
1234

$ kill 1234
```

#### Method #3 - pkill

If you're sure it's the only `wget` you've run you can use the command `pkill` to kill the job by name.

#### Example

```
$ pkill wget
```

#### Method #4 - jobs

If you're in the same shell from where you ran the job that's now backgrounded. You can check if it's running still using the `jobs` command, and also kill it by its job number.

#### Example

My fake job, `sleep`.

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 4542
```

Find it's job number. **NOTE:** the number 4542 is the process ID.

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 100 &

$ kill %1
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 100
```

#### Method #5 - fg

You can bring a backgrounded job back to the foreground using the `fg` command.

#### Example

Fake job, `sleep`.

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 4650
```

Get the job's number.

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 100 &
```

Bring job #1 back to the foreground, and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

```
$ fg 1
sleep 100
^C
$
```

Comment: The `jobs` has no `output` and `fg ` sais: `-bash: fg: 1: no such job`. But typing `fg` works well and also `pkill wget` works well. but `ps -eaf|grep wget` and then `kill <process number>` dose not stop the job. ps: I use the third number as **process number**.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar - use the 2nd number from the output of `ps`. The 3rd # is the parent's process id.

Comment: When I use the second number, It sais: `No such process` and then when I check the process number again using `ps -eaf|grep wget` I find that the process number has changed.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar - I'd need to see the output from `ps`. It sounds like you have a script running multiple wget's or something is restarting wget's after it's killed..

Comment: The command `ps -eaf|grep wget` gives the `grep wget` process. `ps -efa|grep <my user id>` gives [this](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1369).

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar - ah, the ps is finding the grep. Do it like this: `ps -eaef| grep [w]get`.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar - you can also use `pgrep` instead, `pgrep wget`.

Comment: Would you please tell a little about the functionality of option `eaef`?

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar - sorry the extra e is a typo. Should read `ps -eaf | grep [w]get`. The options are are in the `ps` man page. `man ps`.

Comment: Suddenly, on RHEL5 my job was not killed by `Ctrl-C` after `fg` (method 5 did not work.). Method 4 seems to be the fastest and the shortest to type.

Comment: It's `fg %1` to bring the job back into foreground.

Comment: @JackChi - the `fg 1` notation works as well. Try it.

Comment: I did the first, second and third steps, it didnt work, so I just closed the current open tag where I opened the programs, and problem solved

Comment: `kill %%` kills the last background process. Repeating it will kill the one before and so on.
`kill %1` kills the first background process.

Comment: what does [ ] do in grep [w]get?

Comment: @avm - it basically tricks `grep` into not showing the actual `grep` command in the output. The `grep` command shows up as `grep [w]get` but the command `grep` is looking for the string `wget`. The `[...]` is a set of characters, in this case a set of 1 character, `w`.

Comment: But if you launched this process yourself, you should already have the pid of this background process.

Comment: you can also kill all background jobs `kill $(jobs -p)`

Answer (score 134):

In bash you can use `fg` to get the job to the foreground and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Or list the process in the background with `jobs` and then do

```
kill %1
```

(with 1 replaced by the number `jobs` gave you)

Comment: This sleeps the job. Not remove it... `kill -9 %6` is the correct command that will remove the job number `6`. Number `9` indicates type of the signal that `kill` command sends.

Comment: Also useful: to kill multiple jobs by their specific numbers, can do `kill %{1,2,3,4}` (should work in bash/zsh).

Answer (score 36):

You can equally use `kill $!` to kill the most recently backgrounded job.

Comment: If it's used as a command like an alias in a bash profile, be sure to wrap in single quotes.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: Once in the foreground, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or as @Zelda mentions, kill with the '%x' where 'x' is the job number will send the default signal (most likely SIGTERM in the case of Linux).

just type `fg` to bring it to the foreground, if it was the last process you backgrounded (with '&').

If it was not the last one, type: `jobs` and find the 'job number', represented in '[]'.  Then just type:

```
fg 2
```

..where '2' is the job number, for example:

```
foo@bar:~/junk/books$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 okular how_to_cook_a_turkey.pdf &
foo@bar:~/junk/books$ fg 1
okular how_to_cook_a_turkey.pdf            <- this is now in the foreground.
```

Answer (score 7):

It's an old question and there are already few good answers, but, I'll try to present mine in a little different way.

Actually, backgrounded processes are called *jobs*, and job control is very well explained in those 3 short pages: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html

Basically, we can reference a job by a *jobspec*, that is the symbol `%` follow either by another symbol (or a sequence in some fancier cases), or by a job ID. And it's the same for `kill`, `fg`, `bg` or `disown`.

- `%+` (or just `%`, or `%%`) will reference the latest backgrounded
  job (current)
- `%-` will reference the previous one
- `%{jobid}` will reference the specified job

To list your backgrounded jobs, you use the command `jobs`.

### Note

`kill $!` has a different behavior, it will kill the latest process sent in the background as a job, and not the latest job created.

### e.g

You have sent 5 jobs in the background.

You bring back job #2 in the foreground (`fg %2`, or just `%2`), then sent it back in the background (`<Ctrl-Z>`, then `bg`).

It is the latest process sent to the background, but it remains job #2.

So that `kill $!` will terminate job #2 - the latest process (re)sent to the background, while `kill %+` will kill job #5, the latest job that have been created ("current job"):

```
$ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 1000 &
[2]   Running                 sleep 2000 &
[3]   Running                 sleep 3000 &
[4]-  Running                 sleep 4000 &
[5]+  Running                 sleep 5000 &
$ fg %2
sleep 2000
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 sleep 2000
$ bg
[2]+ sleep 2000 &
$ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 1000 &
[2]   Running                 sleep 2000 &
[3]   Running                 sleep 3000 &
[4]-  Running                 sleep 4000 &
[5]+  Running                 sleep 5000 &
$ kill %+
$ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 1000 &
[2]   Running                 sleep 2000 &
[3]   Running                 sleep 3000 &
[4]-  Running                 sleep 4000 &
[5]+  Terminated              sleep 5000
$ kill $!
[2]   Terminated              sleep 2000
$ jobs
[1]   Running                 sleep 1000 &
[3]-  Running                 sleep 3000 &
[4]+  Running                 sleep 4000 &
```

Answer (score 6):

One thing I don't see here, which I've found very useful especially when testing out commands, is `pidof`. You can use `pidof [command]` to find the process id of a process that is currently running. I like it because it allows me to quickly find the id of the command I want, which is usually something I just invoked.

Once you have the pid, you can simply kill the process. It allows for creating simple scripts for killing a process only if it's currently running.

Comment: Ah this helped me! kill %1 wasn't working for some reason, "kill: failed to parse argument: '%1'" and Ctrl+C wasn't working; couldn't find process in ps or anything because it was root (I forgot I used sudo with it)

Answer (score 6):

in bash last stopped process (Ctrl-Z) you will kill by:

```
kill %%
kill -9 %%
```

or if want to choose, use:

`jobs`

then:

`kill %N`

like `kill %2`

Comment: Nice! Does `%%` always refer to the most recent background job?

Answer (score 4):

The correct way is to type `jobs` then use the job number to kill it. In order to use the pid to kill it you need to bring it to the foreground as noted in the first answer.

Try this

```
~/Desktop$ sleep 1000 &
[1] 7056

~/Desktop$ jobs

[1]+  Running  sleep 1000 &

/Desktop$ kill %1  #(%1 is the job number)
```

If you run jobs right after you kill it you should see this

```
Desktop$ jobs
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

The Easiest way is to use `-9` flag on `kill`  command

```
user@host:/path> jobs
[1]+  Running                 /usr/home/script1.sh $i &
user@host:/path> fg
/usr/home/script1.sh $i
^C
[1]+  Stopped                 /usr/home/script1.sh $i
user@host:/path> kill -9 %1
[1]+  Stopped                 /usr/home/script1.sh $i
user@host:/path>
[1]+  Killed                  /usr/home/script1.sh $i
user@host:/path>
user@host:/path> jobs
user@host:/path>
```

Answer (score 1):

A common example is the `stress` tool. Let say you ran the following:

```
$ stress -c 4 -m 4
```

and closed the terminal window. The process would continue eating your resources from the background.

Hers’s what I do:

```
$ x=`pgrep stress` ; sudo kill -9 $x
```

`pgrep` lists the PIDs of the subjected process and stores it into variable `x` which then used by `kill -9` to terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

**List All Jobs by typing**

```
jobs
```

Output>>[1]+  Stopped   sudo nano ls.txt

**Take this process to foreground and kill**

```
fg %1
then press ctrl+c
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the currently-accepted answer, and moreover won't work in this case. Using `kill %1` (as suggested by others) will, but Ctrl+C is meaningless against programs that ignore the keyboard interrupt as mentioned in this question

Answer (score 0):

I am lazy and I got bit tired googling what incantation of `ctrl` `%` `signal number` `fg` `bg` `jobs` `disown` and god knows what else to use for something which should be trvial.
I recommend looking around for cli alternatives to commonly used commands in general as productivity boost as for anything to do with running processes I can't recommend `btop` enough I won't tell you how to use it because its actually made to be used by humans.
I bet its available via package manager of your choice give it a shot you won't look back there is also very nice `procs`.